# Regex extractor in jmeter for selected option

Tags: jmeter

From the HTML code I have to fetch value based on variable passed and option selected. for an example please refer below code:

I have Test F as a variable, using regex extractor I have to fetch  value 6666666. Also can we check using regex while fetching value whether variable option is selected or not?
I am beginner and learning regex. Please help with regular expression needed.

```
<option value="11111111">TestA</option>
<option value="22222222">TestB</option>
<option value="33333333">TestC</option>
<option value="44444444">TestD</option>
<option value="55555555">Test E</option>
<option selected="selected" value="6666666">Test F</option>
<option value="77777777">Test G</option>
```

Comment: you must get `selected` option? if not what you expect exactly to happen?

Comment: I have to fetch value of Test F and also want to check whether it is selected = "selected".
If above thing is not valid or cant be done then I just need to fetch value of Test F i..e in above example it is 6666666

Answer (score 0):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) is not the best way to proceed, I would recommend going for [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead

1. To check whether `Test F` option is selected or not:

   ```
   //option[text()='Test F']/@selected
   ```

   [image: JMeter xpath selec attribute]
2. To fetch selection value:

   ```
    //option[text()='Test F']/@value
   ```

   [image: JMeter XPath selection attribute value]
3. You can replace `Test F` with the JMeter Variable reference:

   ```
    //option[text()='${YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE}']/@value
   ```
4. You can combine 2 or more expressions using `|` operator

   [image: JMeter xpath combine]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)